# Как закрепить окно Kivy поверх всех окон?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Я уже много раз пытался найти полностью рабочий способ по данному вопросу.
Нашёл только двух летний [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50314646/always-on-top-window-in-kivy) на основном StackOverflow.

Я проверил способ с [KivyOnTop](https://github.com/JakubBlaha/KivyOnTop), но работает он только на половину, а именно работало это только на Windows и плюс [KivyOnTop](https://github.com/JakubBlaha/KivyOnTop) только закрепляло окно, а открепить уже не мог. (И как я увидел в [pull requests в Github-репозитории KivyOnTop](https://github.com/JakubBlaha/KivyOnTop/pull/2), такая проблема не только у меня)

**Я хотел бы найти нормально работающий способ закрепить окно Kivy поверх других окон.**

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Вы указали `работало это только на Windows`. Наверное, не лишним было бы указать какие требования Вы предъявляете к решению данного вопроса, чтобы пользователи могли понять какую задачу Вы решаете и могут ли они Вам помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Не могу подсказать насчет Linux, но в Windows есть прекрасная библиотека `pywin32`

```
import win32gui
import win32con

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

class AddWarning(FloatLayout):
    pass

class WarningApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.set_title("ht")
        HWND = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'ht')
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(HWND, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 250, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
        return AddWarning()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WarningApp().run()
```

Comment: Да этот способ работает, я знаю. Для Linux такого решения вообще нет?

Comment: Тут уже надо Api Linux смотреть, я не знаю, честно. Но мне кажется Api должно предоставлять такую возможность